# How to move to ELSE condition if element is not visible in IF in selenium

Tags: selenium, if-statement, automation

I am writing a piece of code in which in the if condition I am giving a condition that if the element is displayed they only go to if part otherwise if the element is not displayed then it should go to else part. But whenever it is coming to the if condition, it searches for the element and when it doesn't find it, it gives a timeout exception. What can be done ?

```
    public void addaddress() {
            suites.setupEnviroment();
            WebDriver driver = suites.getWebDriver();
            try {
                //code to find elements

                try {
                      if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='toast lgksToast ']")).isDisplayed()){
                        System.out.println("fail");
                      }
                      else{
                          System.out.println("pass");
                      }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e);  
                    }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

In the above code if element with this xpath (//div[@class='toast lgksToast ']) is not found then its not executing else part
what should i do for thid please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `size()` method with `findElements` and it will start working.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='toast lgksToast ']")).size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("fail");
} else {
    System.out.println("pass");
}
```

Comment: can i know the difference why it was not working before and how it worked for "findelements"?

Comment: yes, if you read the docs for both methods there is recommendation to use [findElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)  whenever checking for non present element. addition to that look for what those method returns. `findElements` returns empty list if no matching elements found whereas `findElement` throws exception if element is not found and hence the `isDisplayed()` method will not be executed unless element found, hope this clears the doubt

Comment: Yep! Understood very well. Thank you!